# Font awesome ttf files not working in android font family

Tags: android, android-fonts, font-awesome-5

I am working on android app, I downloaded font awesome ttf files and added to android studio project. It is not working but if I try with icoomon working fine. Can anyone please help me.

code:

```
<TextView
            android:text="aws"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:fontFamily="@font/fa_brands_400"/>
```

Comment: I think you should use android:fontFamily="@font/fa_brands_400" instead of app:fontFamily="@font/fa_brands_400"

Comment: i tried but it is not working

Comment: font awesome icon are not written on normal characters Unicodes that is why whenever you need to show that icon you need to see that char's unicode and add it like `"\ue909"` this or copy that character which look like a box or some Chinese char

Answer (score 2):

First of all make sure you place your `.ttf` dowloaded file in your `Asset` folder.

Then create a class called `FontAwesome` that extends `TextView` like this

```
  public class FontAwesome extends TextView {


public FontAwesome(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public FontAwesome(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public FontAwesome(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init() {

//Font name should not contain "/".
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
            "fontawesome.ttf");
    setTypeface(tf);
}
```

}

Finally you create your `TextView` as follow

```
<PACKAGE_NAME.Fontawesome
android:id="@+id/userLogin"
android:text="&#xf007;  Login Now"
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="login"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: What API are you using ?

Comment: Because you can set those custom `font` in `font-family` from API 26 and above. Maybe you are using a lower API. Please accept the answer if this helps you :)

Comment: And don't forget to add the `appcompat` library in your gradle file if it's not already there.

Comment: except font-awesome remaining all fonts are working fine

Comment: Take a look at this link [link text](https://medium.com/@He_Is_Noel/fontawesome-on-android-apps-api-26-goodness-2c8a8dc399aa)